# What two types of lossy audio are the best to compare quality and efficiency?

Tags: audio, mp3, aac, ogg

I'm planning to do a detailed research about comparing and contrasting two lossy audio type formats. However, now I'm struggling to determine the two types which I can do a lot of experiments and detailed comparisons on it. (which are the best to compare their efficiency on encoding as well as audio quality after encoding)

Could you recommend me the two types that I can do an experiment on and produce clear results that I can derive a conclusion on? Currently planning to compare either 'MP3 or OGG', or 'MP3 or AAC' codec, but not sure which can make the best comparison.

Answer (score 0):

FLAC and WMA are the best formats for quality and least amount of compression.
A really good comparison and explanation site is:
https://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/62412/audio_compression_formats_compared/

Comment: WMA? Puhleease no. Compatibility, 1 platform, Windows.